# Having issue in decrypt the data using Cipher Class

Tags: apex, encryption, commerce-cloud, decrypt, b2c

I have a requirement to encrypt data in Salesforce Apex, and the other team will decrypt the data using a common private key.

However, I made some modifications to the code.
below is the code to encrypt the url using the key

```
Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(customSetting.Encryption_Key__c);
Blob psIV = Blob.valueOf('someText');
Blob cipherText = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', key, psIV, Blob.valueOf(clearText));
String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText);
String encodedId = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(encodedCipherText, 'UTF-8');
String url = "?id=" + encodedId;
```

We pass the value of Encryption_Key__c and the encrypted URL to the Commerce Cloud team. However, they are encountering an error in their code. Here is the code they are using:

```
var Msg = 'h4z8l%2FTiOgUtrj%2B5rFictPk85CSOPcJrnAbt8bxAbcic0CzDho2wZZz1r32ZXw%3D%3D';
var decodedMsg = Encoding.fromURI(Msg, 'UTF-8');
var decodedMsg2 = Encoding.fromBase64(decodedMsg);

var hashKey = 'aCyAMzeZrmg=='; // Private key

var saltOrIV = 'someText';
var base64SaltOrIV = StringUtils.encodeBase64(saltOrIV);

var cipher = new Cipher();
var dataDecrypted = cipher.decrypt(decodedMsg2, hashKey, "AES/ECB/NOPADDING", base64SaltOrIV, 0);
```

They are receiving an error in the code: "Invalid length of AES."

These Key and data is just for demo purpose not using these one.

Comment: AES encrypt in Apex uses CBC mode, thus decrypt should follow suit.